# How do I set the Emacs fill-column for a specific mode?

Tags: emacs, clojure, autofill

I would like to set the `fill-column` in Emacs to 120 for Clojure-mode, but leave it at the default (80) otherwise.

How can I do this in my `.emacs` file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Add a call to `set-fill-column` to the `clojure-mode-hook`.

```
(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (set-fill-column 120)))
```

As `fill-column` is buffer local, it won't affect other buffers. In fact, you can invoke `M-x set-fill-column RET 120` to set the fill column in any Emacs buffer interactively.

You can check if a variable is buffer local by invoking the help: `C-h v fill-column` specifies:

> Automatically becomes buffer-local when set in any fashion.

Answer (score 2):

fill-column is a buffer-local variable, i.e. it can have unique value in each buffer (if you want). So you can just set it in clojure-mode hook.

Comment: For more information see the Emacs Wiki page on buffer-local variables: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BufferLocalVariable

Also see Sect. 11.10 of the Emacs Manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer_002dLocal-Variables.html#Buffer_002dLocal-Variables