# fill-column setting in tuareg mode not working

Tags: emacs, tuareg

I have following setting in ~/.emacs

```
(defun my-fillcol-hook ()
   (longlines-mode t)
   (setq-default fill-column 80))                                                                                                                                                                                 

(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my-fillcol-hook)
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'my-fillcol-hook)
(add-hook 'tuareg-mode-hook 'my-fillcol-hook)
```

The fill-column is set as expected in C-mode and C++-mode but not in tuareg-mode. I am not able to find out why fill-column is not getting set in tuareg-mode. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set the Emacs fill-column for a specific mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080495/how-do-i-set-the-emacs-fill-column-for-a-specific-mode)

Comment: See the above thread for a way to set the `fill-column`.  FWIW, `setq-default` should go *outside* of a mode hook, with a regular `setq` inside the mode hook.  If you did the former, you would essentially be resetting the default value every time you entered a buffer of that particular mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setq-default` changes the *global* value, whereas tuareg-mode apparently sets a buffer-local value which takes precedence.  IOW you want to use `setq-local` or just `setq`.